# Linq multiple left outer joins with grouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a player class object which contains an image as one of it's properties. I am trying to do a left join to an equipments class and a left join to a social class. I want to retrieve all players and if the player has equipment or social properties, set accordingly, if the equipment or social is null, leave as null but still show the player.

I am currently getting a "The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable." error. The query I am trying to do:

```
var player = (from p in db.Players
              join e in db.Equipment on p.PlayerId equals e.PlayerId
              into playerequipment
              from d in playerequipment.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join so in db.Social on p.PlayerId equals so.PlayerId
              into playersocial
              from de in playersocial.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where p.PlayerId == PlayerId
              group new { p, d, de } by new
              {
                  Player = p
              } into x
              select new 
              { 
                  Player = x
              });
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of the group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Navigation Properties:

```
var players = db.Players.Where(player=> player.Equipment != null && player.Social != null).ToList();
```

No clue if your Navigation Properties are named this way though... Check your model.

If you want to retrieve them regardless of the presence of Social or Equipment:

```
var players = db.Players.Include("Social").Include("Equipment").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using EF code first and have foreign keys like so: public Equipment Equipment { get; set } and public Social Social { get; set; } as properties inside the player class. Therefore the Any keyword isn't available

Comment: @Dan if you dont have the foreign keys it will be harder. i would set them up in this case ... saves a lot of work as you can see.

Comment: @Dan Oh i see then you can just check for Equipment != null and Social != null... editing answer...

Comment: @Dan thought of these relationships as 1 to many if it's 1:1 it would work like this

Comment: @Dan try the statement below... it should map the players and their navigation properties

Comment: The one with the .include part

Comment: @Dan if this does not work you probably have an error in your classes and you should add the respective code to your question to find it